# Reformat number groups

Tags: notepad++

I need to find a string  for example: 20140605 and I'd like to change the `20140605` to `yyyy-mm-dd` format without changing characters, just separating year from month and from day... 
I tried with regular expression like

```
([0-9]{4}+)([0-9]{2}+)([0-9]{2}+)
```

but it didn't even find the string.

What's the right regex for this case? My notepad is 5.8.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

find what: `\b([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})\b`
Replace with: `$1-$2-$3`

Comment: M42, thanks but that doesn't work.. I posted in the previous commment an example of where I need to find those numbers...

Comment: @Luigino: It works fine for me. Did you check the radio button `Regular expression` ?

Comment: yes, since it's a regex expression I checked Regular Expression but it didn't worked...

Comment: OK, had to upgrade my notepad to latest version 6.6.1 since it was up to version 5.8.2 which is pretty old and now it works as you said.

Answer (score 0):

`([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})` is probably what you're looking for. `{4}` means there has to be four of the previous items, adding `+` after it won't work.

Comment: The sentence for example is this one:

INSERT INTO dbo.customers(ID, firstname, lastname, address, email, password, vatnumber, note, businessname, zipcode, city, countrycode, interno, phone, date, lastlogin, languageID, survey, active, fiscalcode, citycode) VALUES ( 4, 'XXXXXX', 'XXXXXXX', 'XXXXXXXXX', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX', 'XXXXXXX', 'XXXXXXXX', '', 'XXXXXXXX', 'XXXXX', 'XXXXXXXXXX', 'IT', 1, 'XXXXXXXXX', '20110107 13:03:00.000', '20110919 16:10:00.000', 2, NULL, 1, NULL, NULL );

and I tried that you said but it didn't found those numbers like 20110107 and 20110919 to reformat them....